# Flutter: read email in gmail

Tags: flutter

I need to trigger a notification if a certain keyword appears in the mail body. Is there a way in Flutter to read mail from Gmail so that I can trigger the notification.

Comment: How are you accessing Gmail?

Comment: I am not sure how can I access gmail in my app. I could not find any blog to access gmail and read content from my app.

Comment: Did u find a solution?